# Java List<String> to Map<String, Long> convertion

Tags: java, list, java-8

is there any way to convert Java List to Map in Java 8?
I have a List which I want to add the contents to Map

Comment: There are many ways.  Details depend on how the elements of the list are supposed to relate to the entries in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the class SomeType has a constructor and two fields named id and name

```
List<SomeType> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SomeType(1, "a"));
        list.add(new SomeType(2, "b"));
        list.add(new SomeType(3, "c"));

        Map<Integer, String> result = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(SomeType::getId, SomeType::getName));
```

Comment: unless list contains duplicates

Comment: exactly . @Eugene

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have created a List named slist and a Map named map which is initialized from HashMap
To create a map from list you need to run a for loop on the list.

```
for(String skey: slist){
        map.put(skey,yourLongValue); //Enter any Long value you desire or create a method which gets value dynamically like getLongValue()
}
```